# Issue using while loop in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, loop, while

I am trying to write an iterative procedure using the GEE Code Editor. I initially calculate a variable "AR" and if this variable is greater than a specified threshold, then an iterative procedure is repeated until the AR value is below the threshold value. I am uncertain about the most efficient way to achieve this result given the client/server constraints of the IDE. In my example, I need to use a `.getInfo()` call to retrieve the AR value, or else it will not be recognized and passed into the while loop. Unless there is a different way to do this?  I understand this is not the best practice, especially within the loop. Please see my example code below...

```
var calculate_adjustment_ratio = function(x, y){
  
  // ENTER TOTAL FROM MODELED DEFORESTATION
  var modeled_deforestation = ee.Number(x)

  // ENTER EXPECTED AMOUNT OF DEFORESTATION
  var expected_deforestation = ee.Number(y)

  // CALCULATE ADJUSTMENT RATIO
  var AR = expected_deforestation.divide(modeled_deforestation)
  print(AR, 'Adjustment Ratio')
  
  return AR
}

// ENTER INITIAL INPUT PARAMETERS TO CALCULATE THE ADJUSMENT RATIO
var modeled_deforestation = 1.75
var expected_deforestation = 3

// CALCULATE INITIAL ADJUSTMENT RATIO (AR)
var AR = calculate_adjustment_ratio(modeled_deforestation,expected_deforestation).getInfo()

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var update_modeled_deforestation = function(modeled_deforestation, update_deforestation){
  var updated = ee.Number(modeled_deforestation).add(ee.Number(update_deforestation))
  return updated
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var maxIterations = 10
var iterationCount = 0
var adjustmentValue = 0.5

// IF THE INITIAL AR IS GREATER THAN 1.00001, ITERATE LOOP UNTIL AR >= 1.00001
while (AR > 1.00001 && iterationCount <= maxIterations) {
  var modeled_deforestation_new = update_modeled_deforestation(modeled_deforestation, adjustmentValue)
  AR = calculate_adjustment_ratio(modeled_deforestation_new,expected_deforestation).getInfo()
  iterationCount++
  adjustmentValue = adjustmentValue + 0.5;
  
  // Print intermediate AR value
  print("Intermediate AR (iteration " + iterationCount + "):", AR);
}

if (iterationCount <= maxIterations) {
  print("AR should be less than 1.00001")
} else {
  print("Maximum number of iterations reached");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I typically use `iterate()`. It is essentially the same as JavaScript's `reduce()`. It takes two arguments, the first is a function that will be invoked for each element in a list/collection, getting passed the element itself and an accumulated value. The returned value in this function will be the next accumulated value, or the resulting value of `iterate()` if it is the last element in the list/collection. Second argument is the initial value, the one being passed to the function together with the first element in your list/collection.

There is no way to short-cut it like you do with `while()`. All iterations will always be completed.

Here's how you can use it - I might have gotten your specific algorithm wrong, but you should get the idea.

```
var modeled_initial = 1.75
var expected = ee.Number(3)
var maxIterations = 9

var adjustmentValues = ee.List.sequence({start: 0.5, step: 0.5, count: maxIterations})

var finalModel = ee.Number(
  adjustmentValues
    .iterate( // iterate() is essentially a JavaScript reduce()
      function (adjustment, modeled) {
        // Arguments must always be cast to correct type
        adjustment = ee.Number(adjustment)
        modeled = ee.Number(modeled)
        var AR = ee.Number(expected).divide(modeled)
        // Instead of short cutting once you reach your AR threshold, 
        // just don't do any update when that is the case
        return ee.Algorithms.If(
          AR.gt(1.00001),
          modeled.add(adjustment),
          modeled
        )
      },
      modeled_initial // First
    )
)
print(finalModel)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0a212c55e4ad2cb0fa1c565ca0c5235f